# This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching -> Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

Tags: android, react-native

Installing the Android studio SDK packages as per the [react native get started](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) documentation.
And I have changed the Installation directory from default C Drive AppData... to D Drive due to space contraints in C drive.

Now facing the following error in -
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-31_r03.zip

> This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying
> without caching.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/20930 Check this out for detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk then search for system-images folder and delete it.... Then restart android studio